# how to load rasa model and run inference on top of it

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have trained my rasa model with 100 records which are properly tagged and the sample code looks as follows.

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data  import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa_nlu import config
from rasa_nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter

train_data = load_data('rasa_dataset.json')
trainer = Trainer(config.load("config_spacy.yaml"))

trainer.train(train_data)
model_directory = trainer.persist('projects/')
interpreter = Interpreter.load(model_directory)
print(interpreter.parse(u"ji bilkul han ji bilkul isliye payment nahi kara tha humne kitne mein likha aapko this rupay discount de dia to phir aap jama kar dena"))
```

when I execute this I get an output something like this

```
{'intent': None, 'entities': [{'start': 93, 'end': 108, 'value': 'discount de dia', 'entity': 'Waiver else Wont Pay', 'confidence': 0.4628098345881119, 'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor'}], 'intent_ranking': [], 'text': 'ji bilkul han ji bilkul isliye payment nahi kara tha humne kitne mein likha aapko this rupay discount de dia to phir aap jama kar dena'}
```

but when run just inference on the model as-in when I execute the following code.

```
$ cat inference_rasa.py
from rasa_nlu.training_data  import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa_nlu import config
from rasa_nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter

trainer = Trainer(config.load("config_spacy.yaml"))
model_directory = trainer.persist('/home/vz/goutham_Openseq/ner/rasa/projects/default/model_20190706-004103/')
interpreter = Interpreter.load(model_directory)
print(interpreter.parse(u"ji bilkul han ji bilkul isliye payment nahi kara tha humne kitne mein likha aapko this rupay discount de dia to phir aap jama kar dena"))
```

I get output as follows.

```
(gp) vz@andromeda:~/goutham_Openseq/ner/rasa$ python inference_rasa.py
{'intent': None, 'entities': [], 'intent_ranking': [], 'text': 'ji bilkul han ji bilkul isliye payment nahi kara tha humne kitne mein likha aapko this rupay discount de dia to phir aap jama kar dena'}
```

Its the same sample which I'm trying to infer in the above code and the below code yet I could get confidence in the above code i.e before training and not when I just run inference on the saved model.

Can anyone help me out in the mistake I am doing and help me on this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second snippet, you should load interpreter from model_directory created in the first snippet, but you override model_directory with untrained model, by persisting untrained Trainer there. So you should remove trainer from the second snippet and load interpreter directly from the path

Comment: Thanks @Vova Vv it worked like a charm . so silly of me :) .